# Use CM Roman (latex font) in Inkscape?

Tags: fonts, latex, inkscape

I made a SVG in Inkscape on Fedora with the CM Roman (latex) font, but when opening the SVG on Ubuntu 12.04, it says it doesn't have CM Roman even though TexLive is installed.

How do I use the CM Roman font in Inkscape on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should actually download and install a ttf or otf version of the Computer Modern Roman font in order to be able to use it in inkscape. I did it in the past, but I have to look up the download link. This might do it: http://cm-unicode.sourceforge.net/download.html. You could also check (and maybe copy) your Fedora fonts directory.

Answer (score 24):

It is actually very easy to get the Computer Modern fonts working under Ubuntu, because the fonts can be installed directly from the Ubuntu repositories

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-cmu
```

"cmu" is short for "cm-unicode". The fonts appear as "CMU Serif" and "CMU Sans Serif" etc. in font selection screens.

This has been tested with version Kubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Further help (in German) related to fonts can be found at http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Schriftarten

Comment: Thanks, works also on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the most general answer is to install the package *cm-super*.
It contains Computer Modern font families, including those of the package *fonts-cmu*.

```
sudo apt-get install cm-super
```

Comment: No, on Ubuntu 17.10 i had `cm-super` installed, but had to install `fonts-cmu` afterwards.  It is not a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Export your Inkscape file as a PDF. This will automatically **embed** the **fonts**.

I've tested this with Inkscape installed under Windows 10 and Latex as used as part of a pandoc docker-container.

Worked like a charm.